# Populating multiple lists with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, windows, list, for-loop, multiprocessing

I'm trying to increase the speed of a function populating multiple lists which was taking +150 seconds sequentially. I managed to make it faster with Multiprocessing, down to +20 seconds, but I'm running in 2 issues :
1- How can I "stop" and "prevent" Multiprocessing from running the rest of the script ?
2- Is there an even faster way(Multithreading, Asyncio...) ?

```
## IMPORTS ##
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool


##
## HEADERS
##

##LISTING POPUPS

def loop_through(popup_id_list, popup_name_list, i):
    all_popups_url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/popup?popup_category=216&per_page=100&page="
    popups_url = all_popups_url + str(i)
    # print(popups_url)
    response = requests.get(popups_url, headers=headers)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    if response.status_code==200:
      response = response.json()
      # print(popups_url)
      for id in response :
          popup_id = (id['id'])
          # print(popup_id)
          popup_id_list.append(popup_id)
          popup_name = html.unescape((id['title'])['rendered']).encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
          popup_name_list.append(str(popup_name))
          # print(html.unescape(popup_name))
    else:
      pass

popup_name_list =[]
popup_id_list =[]
popup_full_list=[]

def popup_listing():
    print("Listing Popups...")
    global popup_name_list
    global popup_id_list
    popup_name_list =[]
    popup_id_list =[]
    # if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        i = range(1,100)
        popup_id_list = manager.list()  # <-- can be shared between processes.
        popup_name_list = manager.list()
        processes = []

        for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
            p = Process(target=loop_through, args=(popup_id_list, popup_name_list, i,))  # Passing the list
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

        for p in processes:
            p.join()
            p.terminate()

        popup_id_list = list(popup_id_list)
        popup_name_list = list(popup_name_list)

    global popup_full_list
    popup_full_list= zip(popup_id_list, popup_name_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    popup_listing()
    print(len(popup_name_list))
print("Hello")
```

Current Ouput :

```
Listing Popups...
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
808
Hello
[Finished in 19.892s]
```

Desired Output :

```
Listing Popups...
808
Hello
```

Comment: `print("Hello")` must be indented under `if __name__ == '__main__':` if you don't want it to run in the child processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an OP posts a question tagged with `regex` they are supposed to specify what language they are using since different programming languages support different regular expression facilities. Similarly, it's supposed to be a requirement that when an OP posts a question tagged with `multiprocessing` they should specify what platform they are running under since multiprocessing is implemented *by default* quite differently under Linux and Windows. But it is fairly clear that you are running under Windows by the symptoms your code is manifesting.

Windows essentially uses the `spawn` method to create new processes while Linux/Unix by default uses the `fork` method. When a new process is "forked", it inherits all the variables in the same state as the parent process and continues executing from the "forking" point. When a new process is "spawned", nothing is inherited; a new address space is created, a new Python interpreter is loaded and the program is started anew from the top. Thus, everything declared at global scope will be re-executed (this is why it is necessary to place the code that creates new processes within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to avoid getting into an infinite, recursive loop). And *that* is why your `print("Hello")` is being executed over and over -- every new process you are creating will execute that statement because it is at *global scope*.